# C++のテンプレートについて

Tags: c++

この3, 4行目が無いとfunction_traits is not a class templateというコンパイル時エラーが出るのですが、これが無いと駄目な理由がわかりません。コンパイラはgcc7です。

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Signature>
struct function_traits;

template <typename R> \
struct function_traits<R()> \
{ \
  typedef R return_type; \
};

using namespace std;

function_traits<int()>::return_type main()
{
  cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

元はマクロか何かでしょうか？ `\`は不要です。

`template <typename R> struct function_traits<R()>`は`template <typename Signature> struct function_traits`の[部分特殊化](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A%E5%8C%96)です。
ですので、元のテンプレートとして必要です。

なお、`function_traits`は[`std::result_of`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/type_traits/result_of.html)そのものですね。